# std::string Constructed in Arguments

Tags: c++, std

I've run into a very tricky C++ compiler error.

When I construct a string to use as an argument, it works when calling a regular method. E.g. `printThisString(string(charPtr));`

It does not work when constructing an object, if the argument to the constructor is a `char*`. For example, `MyObject a(string(argv[0]));` It still does work if the argument is a literal. For example, `MyObject b(string("hi"));`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printString(string toPrint) {
    cout << toPrint << endl;
}

class MyObject {
    int blah;
public:
    void aMethod() {}
    MyObject (string myStr) {
        cout << myStr << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

string s1(argv[0]);
char * s2 = "C-style string"; // I realize this is bad style

printString(string("Hello world!")); // All of these work
printString(s1);
printString(string(s2));
printString(string(argv[0]));

MyObject mo1 (string("Hello world!")); // Valid
MyObject mo2 (s1); // Valid
MyObject mo3 (string(s2)); // Does not print
MyObject mo4 (string(argv[0])); // Does not print

mo1.aMethod();
mo2.aMethod();
mo3.aMethod(); // Error
mo4.aMethod(); // Error


return 0;
}
```

For mo3 and mo4, the objects can be created, but no methods can be used. They are of the wrong typ. It appears that the compiler thinks they are functions...

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:22:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
test.cpp:36:5: error: request for member 'aMethod' in 'mo3', which is of non-class type 'MyObject(std::string) {aka MyObject(std::basic_string<char>)}'
test.cpp:37:5: error: request for member 'aMethod' in 'mo4', which is of non-class type 'MyObject(std::string*) {aka MyObject(std::basic_string<char>*)}'
```

Comment: Welcome to C++, home of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: Aer you using a compiler supporting C++11?

Comment: This is why you should prefer `Type variable = ...;` declarations. The assignment is elided so it boils down to the same thing as `Type variable(...);` minus the ambiguity. (assuming the constructor is not `explicit`, otherwise you have to write `Type variable = Type(...);` but again it generates the same code)

Comment: What chris says. `MyObject a(string(argv[0]));` is a forward declaration of a function named `a` that takes a `string*` parameter named `argv` (parameters apparently specified with array types are always really pointers) and returns `MyObject`. I'm actually faintly surprised that it's legal to declare a 0-sized array parameter, but there it is.

Comment: That is, in this case it's equivalent to `MyObject a(string *argv);`. Which you would naturally read as being a function declaration, but in another context it might be an object definition, if `string` in that scope is not the type `std::string`, but rather the name of some object that can be multiplied by `argv` (whatever that might be in the same scope). When they say that C++ is a context-sensitive grammar, they are not messing around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a variation of the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): `mo3` and `mo4` are function declarations rather than object definitions. You can fix the problem using

```
MyObject mo3 {string(s2)};
MyObject mo4 {string(argv[0])};
```

or

```
MyObject mo3 ((string(s2)));
MyObject mo4 ((string(argv[0])));
```

or

```
MyObject mo3 = MyObject(string(s2));
MyObject mo4 = MyObject(string(argv[0]));
```

or ...

Comment: Or `MyObject mo2(static_cast<string>(s2));`. But is it too prissy of me to advocate against function-style C casts like `string(s2)`? ;-)

Comment: That makes sense. I still wonder how exactly this works for these objects. mo4 would be a function that returns a `MyObject` instance, but what are its arguments? g++ says its only argument is a `string*`, but how can `string(argv[0])` name a type?

Comment: @user2503216: see my comment on the question above. In a parameter list `string(argv[0])` is the same as `string argv[0]`, which is a valid parameter declaration with the same meaning as `string *argv`.